# GNU parallel saturates one server instead of distributing jobs equally

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am using GNU parallel 20160222. I have four servers configured in my `~/.parallel/sshloginfile`:

```
48/big1
48/big2
8/small1
8/small2
```

when I run, say, 32 jobs, I'd expect parallel to start eight on each server. Or even better, two or three each on *small1* and *small2*, and twelve or so each on *big1* and *big2*. But what it is doing is starting 8 jobs on *small2* and the remaining jobs locally.

Here is my invocation (I actually use a `--profile` but I removed it for simplicity):

```sh
parallel --verbose --workdir . --sshdelay 0.2 --controlmaster --sshloginfile .. \
    "my_cmd {} | gzip > {}.gz" ::: $(seq 1 32)
```

Here is the main question:

1. Is there an option missing that would do a more equal allocation of jobs?

Here is another related question:

2. Is there a way to specify `--memfree`, `--load`, etc. per server? Especially `--memfree`.

Comment: Maybe you could treat yourself to a newer version as your appears 4 years old....

Comment: Getting a newer version is a good idea - given it is all one file. However that version is what is distributed with the corporate server distribution, so I'd only override it if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall GNU Parallel used to fill job slots "from one end". This did not matter if you had way more jobs than job slots: All job slots (both local and remote) would fill up.

It did, however, matter if you had fewer jobs. So it was changed, so GNU Parallel today gives jobs to sshlogins in a round robin fashion - thus spreading it more evenly.

Unfortunately I do not recall which version this change was done. But your can tell if you version does it by running:

```
parallel -vv -t
```

and look at which sshlogin is being used.

Re: --memfree

You can build your own using `--limit`.

I am curious why you want different limits for different servers. The idea behind `--memfree` is that it is set to the amount of RAM that a single job takes. So if there is enough RAM for a single job, a new job should be started - no matter the server.

You clearly have another situation, so explain about that.

Re: upgrading

Look into `parallel --embed`.

Comment: Ole: I have to say, you are the star of this site. Quick, and very clear explanations too. Thanks! As for --memlimit. The use case is that the different servers have different sharing patterns. BTW, if I set memfree as a percentage, I assume it will check that on the server in which the job is run, not on the server from which it is started. Correct?

Comment: @Leo As I wrote this answer I was actually thinking whether % is supported in --memfree, and if not, why not. % is not supported, but it should be possible to do (https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?58245). Also it seems remote memfree is not supported. This, too, should be possible to do (https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?58246).